# LUA: Need detect number of current line in file

Tags: file, lua, line

I'm reading the file from input by characters and when I read an invalid character, I need to know what line it was, eventually what was the number of the characater on current line. In Lua, is there any function or way to detect this? I haven't got a clue. Thanks!
Or is it possible to count \n or something like that?

Comment: `if ch == '\n' then count=count+1 end` ?

Comment: Show your reading method?

Comment: the way moteus wrote it, is perfect, thank you